# How do I run MySQL in medium trust mode?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, asp.net-mvc, mysql-error-1064

I am using .NET Framework 4.0 and MySQL. My service providers allows me to run my website in medium trust mode. When I host my site, the following error is generated:

```
Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
```

To overcome this, I have gone through [these](https://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2010/09/18/mysql-net-4-entity-framework-and-medium-trust-hosting-environments/#comment-1471) [links](http://www.marthijnvandenheuvel.com/2011/04/14/fix-net-4-socketpermission-for-mysql-driver-in-medium-trust/) to run MySQL in medium trust mode.

When I use the code from those links, however, my code works fine with SELECT queries, but when I use an INSERT query, the following error is generated:

```
Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217989/net-2-0-and-mysql-in-medium-trust-mode

Answer (score 0):

I hope options below may help you:

- Be sure your user have write acess your mysqldb
- Right click your web project and click "Add deployable dependencies" ( Before click this , be sure you set your assembly prop "copy to local" as "true" on VS in options window of MySQL assembly.
- Be sure your your application pool on your host settings is set to run with .net framework 4.0 .

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is new implementation for Net 4.0 and it is using reflection that is a no-no for medium trust enviroment.
Use a previous version, I am using version 6.5 with godaddy and it is working just fine.